# Can't style the button using ::after & ::before in CSS

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I've used the `::before` and `::after` elements in my CSS class to put a bottom border in my button, but that doesn't seem to work in my case.
I've positioned the `::before` element tag as `absolute` so that the border would be inside the button, but for some reasons the border extends all the way throughout the page instead of just the button.

```css
.mydiv {
  background-color: #242128;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.mybtn2 {
  border: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-family: Serif;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  background-color: #242128;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.mybtn2::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="mydiv">
    <button class="mybtn2">Hover Me</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your button needs `relative positioning`. Read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). Specifically, "_An absolutely positioned element is an element whose computed position value is absolute or fixed. The top, right, bottom, and left properties specify offsets from the edges of the element's containing block. (**The containing block is the ancestor relative to which the element is positioned.**) If the element has margins, they are added to the offset._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `position: relative;` on `.mybtn2`.

Comment: thanks @Mike so much, forgot to thank you because of being busy in work. Your answer helped me.